# Gitlab Runner - New folder for each build

Tags: deployment, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using Gitlab CI for my project. When I push on develop branch, it runs tests and update the code on my test environment (a remote server).

But the gitlab runner is already using the same build folder : `builds/a3ac64e9/0/myproject/myproject`

But I would like to create a now folder every time :

- `builds/a3ac64e9/1/yproject/myproject`
- `builds/a3ac64e9/2/yproject/myproject`
- `builds/a3ac64e9/3/yproject/myproject`
- and so on

Using this, I could just update my website by changing a symbolic link pointing to the last runner directory.

Is there a way to configure Gitlab Runner this way ?

Comment: According to https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runners-section you cannot

Answer (score 13):

While it doesn't make sense to use your build directory as your deployment directory, you can setup a custom build directory

Open config.toml in a text editor: (more info on where to find it [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html))

Set `enabled = true` under `[runners.custom_build_dir]` (more info [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runners-section))

```
[runners.custom_build_dir]
  enabled = true
```

In your .gitlab-ci.yml file, under `variables` set `GIT_CLONE_PATH`.  It must start with `$CI_BUILDS_DIR/`, e.g. `$CI_BUILDS_DIR/$CI_JOB_ID/$CI_PROJECT_NAME`, which will probably give you what you're looking for, although if you have multiple stages, they will have different job IDs.  Alternatively, you could try `$CI_BUILDS_DIR/$CI_COMMIT_SHA`, which would give you a unique folder for each commit.  (More info [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#custom-build-directories))

```
variables:
    GIT_CLONE_PATH: '$CI_BUILDS_DIR/$CI_JOB_ID/$CI_PROJECT_NAME'
```

> Unfortunately there is [currently an issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/4167) with using `GIT_BUILDS_DIR` in `GIT_CLONE_PATH`, if you're using [Windows and Powershell](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/4167), so you may have to do something like this as a work-around, if all your runners have the same build directory: `GIT_CLONE_PATH: 'C:\GitLab-Runner/builds/$CI_JOB_ID/$CI_PROJECT_NAME'`

You may want to take a look at the [variables available to you](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/) ([predefined variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html)) to find the most suitable variables for your path.

Comment: shouldn't it be GIT_CLONE_PATH: $CI_BUILDS_DIR/$CI_JOB_ID/$CI_PROJECT_NAME instead of GIT_CLONE_PATH: '$CI_BUILDS_DIR/$CI_JOB_ID/$CI_PROJECT_NAME' ?

Comment: @tiguero, For me it works with the quotes.

Comment: Perfect, a combination of both worked for me. Since we needed to shorten the overall characters of the path to avoid the windows 260 characters limit, we used a directory name of C:\builds as build_dir, while we kept the variable "GIT_CLONE_PATH" short while making concurrent builds possible with GIT_CLONE_PATH: ''$CI_BUILDS_DIR/$CONCURRENT_ID/$CI_PROJECT_NAME'' which would result in something like C:\builds\0\project

Answer (score 4):

You might want to read the following answer [Changing the build intermediate paths for gitlab-runner](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/1265/2979)

I'll repost my answer here:

Conceptually, this approach is not the way to go; the build directory is not a deployment directory, it's a temporary directory, to build or to deploy **from**, whereas on a shell executor this could be fixed.

So what you need is to deploy from that directory with a script as per `gitlab-ci.yml` below, to the correct directory of deployment.

```
stages:
- deploy

variables:
  TARGET_DIR: /home/ab12/public_html/$CI_PROJECT_NAME

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
     mkdir -pv $TARGET_DIR
     rsync -r --delete ./ $TARGET_DIR
  tags:
    - myrunner
```

This will move your `projectfiles` in /home/ab12/public_html/

naming your projects as `project1` .. `projectn`, all your projects could use this same `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

Answer (score 1):

You can not achieve this only with Gitlab CI runner configuration, but you can create 2 runners, and assign them exclusively to each branch by using a combination of `only` and `tags` keywords.

Assuming your two branches are named `master` and `develop` and two runners have been tagged with `master_runner` and `develop_runner` tags, your `.gitlab-ci.yml` can look like this:

```
master_job:
   <<: *your_job
   only:
     - master
   tags:
     - master_runner

develop_job:
   <<: *your_job
   only:
     - develop
   tags:
     - develop_runner
```

(`<<: *your_job` is your actual job that you can factorize)